# Need to extract whole sentences which begins with a specific word in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract whole sentences which begins with a specific word in R. Below is the code which i am trying to use but not able to get the desired result. I am new to regular expression concept in R. I want to extract the sentences which begins with word 'database'.

```
 sent <- c("database connection","connection database fail", "fail connection database","database connection is good")
 m <- gregexpr('database.*', sent)
 regmatches(sent, m)
```

Above code gives me the remaining words after word 'database'. But my desired output is:

```
 "database connection", "database connection is good"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `m <- gregexpr('^database.*', sent)`

Comment: Sorry, it is not giving the desired result.

Comment: Perhaps, [`m <- grep('^database\\b', sent, value=TRUE)`](http://ideone.com/r7OMN0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `stringr`

```r
sent <- c("database connection","connection database fail", "fail connection database","database connection is good")
stringr::str_subset(sent, "^database.*")
#> [1] "database connection"         "database connection is good"
```

---

With base R :

```r
sent <- c("database connection","connection database fail", "fail connection database","database connection is good")
grep("^database.*", sent, value = T)
#> [1] "database connection"         "database connection is good"
```

Comment: Thanks Titolondon for your guidance. Its working for me.

Comment: @Kiwi. Glad I could help you. Don't forget to close the quesiton by validating your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're not anchoring the regex to the front of the line. If you use the front anchor (`^`), you'll get the desired result. Here is what your code should look like:

```
sent <- c("database connection","connection database fail", "fail connection database","database connection is good")
m <- gregexpr('^database.*', sent)
regmatches(sent, m)
```

If you want to remove the `character(0)` elements from the result you can have the last line be

```
r <- regmatches(sent, m)
r <- r[lapply(r,length)>0]
```

Comment: Thanks Eli Sadoff, I understood my mistake. Its working. One thing, how can i get rid off [[2]] and [[3]] which says 'character(0)' and just print the matching sentences?

Comment: I added that into the answer.

Comment: Perfect...Thanks a lot. Its working for me. I was struggling from past 1 hour.

Comment: FYI, this  `'^database.*'` regex will also find matches when there is `databases` at the start of the string. Or `database0001`. To match it as a whole word (if needed), use `\\b` after the word and the `.*` is redundant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's true, but for the use case, the simpler regex seemed fine.

Comment: @EliSadoff: if you want a simple regex, use `'^database'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was just using the regex provided to me with as few modifications as possible.